# Convert a ushort[] array to a single ushort in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Having a ushort array, `ushort[]` how can I convert the ushort array `[44,55]` to a single joined ushort `4455`? The array always has two elements.

```
ushort[] test = new ushort[2];
test[0] = 44;
test[1] = 55;
// Here I want to convert the ushort[] to a unique ushort value 4455
usortValue = ?
return usortValue;
```

I was expecting a `.join` function as `String` does, but it's not possible with `ushort`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what would you like to do in case of overflow?

Comment: @DovydasSopa That wouldn't be a problem for me as I only have to join arrays of length 2 always.

Comment: What should happen with a pair like [44,5] - should the result be 445 or 4405 ?

Comment: Voted to close as unclear since you don't tell what happens in various cases, like the length of the array, causing overflow, having various values.

Comment: You told that you only have two values of type `ushort`. But there is still the problem of an overflow e.g. if both values are `ushort.MaxValue`. What should happen in that case? `6553565535` will not match into an `ushort`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'm pretty sure that _values being negative_ will not occur when using `ushort`.

Comment: @Verarind Meh, my bad. Removed that already.

Comment: How about using bitconverter and logical and each byte pair to output a new single ushort value? No idea what the requirement is here but that basically add / merge the 2 ushorts together in to 1 ushort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Aggregate, with the predicate being "convert to string, concatenate, and parse back to a ushort", but sooner or later ([sooner!](http://rextester.com/OKVNY7480)) you're going to overflow.

```
ushort[] test = new ushort[2];
test[0] = 44;
test[1] = 55;
var result = test.Aggregate((p,c)  => ushort.Parse((p.ToString() + c.ToString())));
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/VKV9570

Comment: This code returns result as `5544` - is that really what the OP wanted?

Comment: @MatthewWatson - no, I possibly have the `c` and `p` the wrong way round :D (Now fixed)

Answer (score 2):

How about converting numbers to string and joining them?

```
var result =string.Join("",test.Select(x=>x.ToString()));       
Convert.ToUInt16(result);
```

[`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rpYC5N)

Answer (score 1):

```
ushortValue = Convert.ToUInt16(test[0].ToString() + test[1].ToString());
```